# AWS Lambda in VPC accessing RDS with DynamoDB as Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I want to ask a possible fault in this design:

I have AWS Lambda in VPC which accesses RDS. It's pretty slow because of the cold starts (large part of it because of accessing RDS as lambda would have to create ENI)

Now, what if I present DynamoDB before accessing RDS? if there's no record in dynamodb, I'll access RDS in the next step.

Will this improve the overall performance of the system?

Thanks

Comment: I would prefer using AWS Elasticache Redis or Memcached over Dynamodb for this purpose.

Comment: That's what I thought at first.. But AWS Elasticache will also have the penalty of VPC cold starts + creating ENI

Comment: AWS Elasticcache is not even driven, so provisioning will happen ones where it needs to create ENIs. You can keep your Lambda's hot using CloudWatch to avoid Cold Starts and it won't cost you much.

Comment: Ah ok.. But the behavior of creating ENI from RDS and Elasticache is similar right? And I have 100+ functions in my lambda (each of them for the REST API). Is pinging all functions a good idea?

Comment: Don't ping all the functions. Focus on the area of the application which will impact the feel of the performance.

Comment: Ah OK! I think I get the idea. Is there any best practices regarding the number of lambda functions that I should ping frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your AWS Lambda function is **attached to an Amazon VPC**, then the *warmup* time required to attach the ENI would still be required whether accessing Amazon RDS, Amazon DynamoDB or Amazon ElastiCache. They all require a connection to the VPC, even if it is just to gain Internet access.

If you used DynamoDB exclusively (without Amazon RDS), you could choose to ***not* attach the Lambda function** to the VPC and this would reduce the warmup time.

See: [How to manage Lambda VPC cold starts and deal with that killer latency](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lambda-vpc-cold-starts-a-latency-killer-5408323278dd)

Comment: Hmm what if I use both in the lambda? first one is DynamoDB, if record exist, return, if no record, I'll use RDS. Would it still be affected by the long cold start if there's a record in DynamoDB?

Comment: Yes. To access DynamoDB, the Lambda function (which is connected to a VPC) will need to access the ENI in the VPC to go out through the Internet Gateway to the DynamoDB endpoint. No benefit from a warmup perspective because the problem is not with the RDS database, but rather the ENI itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So I guess we'd have to deal with this until AWS (hopefully) work this out somehow.